# Display list in a list with Gtk

Tags: python, list, gtk

So I have a list in a list that looks like

```
[('9/13/2021', 2.0, '7:15', 'Hill'), 
('9/14/2021', 8.0, '6:0', 'Tempo'), 
('9/14/2021', 4.0, '6:0', 'Tempo')]
```

and I understand how to print it out to look good but I am trying to get it to display in Gtk and it prints into the display looking like this:

[image]

I am looking for a way to get it to print out where it gets rid of the brackets, commas and quotation marks but is still within the same line.

The way I am printing to the is like this:

```
        items = self.read_from_db()
        # lists through the items pulled and adds them to the
        # list of reminders displayed
        for item in items:
            self.listbox_2.add(ListBoxRowWithData(item))
```

Where `read_from_db()` returns the lists within a list. Any thoughts?

Here is the ListBoxRowWithData class:

```
class ListBoxRowWithData(Gtk.ListBoxRow):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.add(Gtk.Label(label=data))
```

```
Items output:
 [('9/13/2021', 2.0, '7:15', 'Hill'), ('9/14/2021', 8.0, '6:0', 'Tempo'), ('9/14/2021', 4.0, '6:0', 'Tempo')]
```

Comment: Try changing the `self.listbox_2...` line to `self.listbox_2.add(ListBoxRowWithData(" ".join(item)))`.

Comment: I get the error `self.listbox_2.add(ListBoxRowWithData(" ".join(item))) TypeError: can only join an iterable`

Comment: Please edit the question to include the value of `item`, as it looks like the inner lists are actually strings.

Comment: Edited. It is 3 strings and a float.

Comment: `.join` does not work unless all the list items are strings. Try 
 `self.listbox_2.add(ListBoxRowWithData(" ".join([str(x) for x in item])))` instead. That list comprehension will make sure everything is a string so it can be joined.

Comment: That works, thank you! Do you want to make it an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the label text is a string representation of the list. To join the list into a string, you can use the `.join` of a string.

```
self.listbox_2.add(ListBoxRowWithData(" ".join([str(x) for x in item])))
```

`.join` will only work if all the items in the list are strings, so the `[str(x) for x in item]` list comprehension will convert every list item to a string. The items are then joined with a space but you can use a different joining string if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the list comprehension, I someone always forget it exists when I need it most!